# Duplicating an element of a list back into the list in Python

Tags: python, list, copy, mutable

Copying an element back into the list:

```
>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>> b = []
>> b = a[1]
>> a.insert(1,b)
>> a
[[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]]
>> a[2][0] = 0
>> a
???
```

What do you expect list 'a' to be? It comes out to be as [[1,2],[0,4],[0,4]] which was very surprising to me whereas I expected [[1,2],[1,4],[0,4]]

I kind of know the answer but still, the idea is not very clear. Kindly tell in more detail why does this happen and how to get rid of it?

Comment: read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Also,the line `b = []` is totally useless, you immediately reasign `b`...

Comment: By doing `b = []`, I was trying to allocate space for a list `b` in the memory. But then I found another way of doing this which is `b = list (a[1])` which makes a new object for `b` rather than just a pointer to `a[1]`.

Comment: Those are semantically different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = a[1]
a.insert(1,b)
```

`b` is a reference to `a[1]` so when you modify the reference after inserting it, it appears in both places since it is essentially pointing to the same data.

if you want to avoid such a scenario, use `deepcopy`

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = []
b = deepcopy(a[1])
a.insert(1,b)
print(a) # prints [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
a[2][0] = 0
print(a) # prints [[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 4]]
```

Comment: I think `deepcopy(a[1])` is doing similar to what `list(a[1])` would do.

Comment: @SunalMittal yes check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list

Comment: But be aware that copy.copy(), list[:] and list(list), unlike copy.deepcopy() and the python version don't copy any lists, dictionaries and class instances in the list, so if the originals change, they will change in the copied list too and vice versa. more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612990/7821988

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because of the way lists work in python, they have what is known as "linked data". If you have an instance pointing to an object in a list, and then modify that object, it will be modified in the list too because the list simply points to the object(s). So:

```
x = [1,2]
b = [1,3]
x[0] = b
b[0] = 2
```

Then printing x would give [[2,3],2] not [[1,3],2].

What's happening in your situation is that you set the object at position 1 of a to be a pointer/variable b. Then you inserted that pointer at position 2 of a. So when you modify position 2 of a, you also modify b, and thus modify position 1 of a.